# Forgotten Pin 2

Tags: geography

After the trouble with the last one I changed my pin and wrote down the following to help me remember what my pin was but I now have no idea what it means!

Japan, Tunisia, Germany, Gabon, Costa Rica

Portugal, South Korea, Brazil, Palau, Latvia

Bangladesh, Kyrgyzstan, Japan, Tunisia, Palau

Yemen, South Korea, Portugal, Kyrgyzstan, Bangladesh

Gambia, Hungary, Tajikistan, Palau, Brazil

Estonia, Botswana, Bulgaria, Luxemburg, Bolivia

Scrawled in the corner were the words ‘What hath God wrought?’ but this means nothing to me. Can’t anyone figure it out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pin is:

> 245680

The message 'What hath God wrought?' refers to:

> the first **Morse code** message

And each country's

> flag features **circles** (dots) or **horizontal lines** (dashes). 
>  Converting each line from Morse code gives us a number for the pin:
>
> ```
>     ..---   2
>     ....-   4
>     .....   5
>     -....   6
>     ---..   8
>     -----   0
> ```